# Could you please explain to me the reason why jQuery is making never ending loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my jQuery code hosted here, https://jsfiddle.net/f7u2yqpe/, would really like to know why is it making never ending loops.

HTML

```
<ul id='user_menu'>
  <li>
    <a class='shopping_cart'>click this</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('#user_menu > li').click(function() { $(this).children('a:first').click(); } );
$('.shopping_cart').click(function(){ alert('hi') });
```

So if I click on the `click me` shouldn't it just invoke the alert only twice, one for the `li` selector and the other one for the `.shopping_cart` selector.

Comment: When you trigger `click` on the children element, the event goes up the DOM tree and trigger on the li, which trigger aigain, etc. Try to use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` in the handler of the children element to fix the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is event bubbling in javascript. When an event is performed on an element that event is propagated up the DOM and fired on every parent of the target element. When you click `a` the event bubbles to the `li` which then triggers a click on `a` again producing an infinite loop

On event bubbling: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

To prevent this you simply explicitly call a stop propagation on the event:

```
$('.shopping_cart').click(function(event){ 
    event.stopImmediatePropagation()
    alert('hi') 
});
```